# Retrieve reference to comment OpenXML

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to pull out the text from a Word document that is referenced by a comment in OpenXML. I can easily get the text of a comment, but not the paragraph text in the document that the comment is referencing.

The image I attached shows a comment and the related text. I am having a lot of trouble finding an example of how to get the referenced text. How can I get this text?

[image: Image of text I need]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to get the Id of the comment which as you said you already know how to retrieve, and then search the document for a CommentRangeStart element with the same Id. When you have found it, you can loop over .NextSibling() until you hit a CommentRangeEnd element.

The elements between CommentRangeStart and CommentRangeEnd is the referenced part, which obviously can be multiple runs, paragraphs, images, whatever. So you will have to handle the collected elements somehow afterwards.

I made a test document looking like this:
[image: document example]

I've made this code to test it:

```
using (var wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"c:\test\test.docx", true))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;
    var document = mainPart.Document;
    var comments = mainPart.WordprocessingCommentsPart.Comments.ChildElements;
    foreach(Comment comment in comments)
    {
        string commentId = comment.Id;
        string commentText = comment.InnerText;
        OpenXmlElement rangeStart = document.Descendants<CommentRangeStart>().Where(c => c.Id == commentId).FirstOrDefault();
        List<OpenXmlElement> referenced = new List<OpenXmlElement>();
        rangeStart = rangeStart.NextSibling();

        while(!(rangeStart is CommentRangeEnd))
        {
            referenced.Add(rangeStart);
            rangeStart = rangeStart.NextSibling();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Comment Id " + commentId + " with text \"" + " " + commentText + "\" references =>");

        foreach (var ele in referenced)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ele.InnerText))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("      " + ele.InnerText);
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Which produces this output
[image: Console output of code]

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! The solution you provided really helped guide me in coming up with a solution for my project.

Comment: If it was the answer you were looking for would you mind accepting it ?

Answer (score 0):

I could not get your solution to work. However I found a workaround.

```
 OpenXmlElement rangeStart = document.Descendants<CommentRangeStart>().Where(c => c.Id == commentId).FirstOrDefault();

                bool breakLoop = false;
                rangeStart = rangeStart.Parent;

 while (true) // Looping through items between commentRangeStart and commentRangeEnd.
                {
                    if (rangeStart.NextSibling() == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    foreach (var ele in rangeStart.ChildElements)
                    {
                        if (!(ele is CommentRangeEnd))
                        {
                            if (!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ele.InnerText)))
                            {
                                referenced.Add(ele);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            breakLoop = true;
                        }
                        if (breakLoop)
                            break;
                    }
                    rangeStart = rangeStart.NextSibling();
                }
```

Hence, instead of looping through the paragraph in which the CommenRageStart exists, since one comment may be built up of several paragraphs, I use the parent node in order to trace back and forth between the paragraphs. Finnaly, as I reach the CommentRangeEnd I can break the loop and process the data however is required.